# Trying to split html tag which is returned by cURL session's result(curl_exec)

Tags: php, split, php-curl

so i am trying to split HTML Tag which is returned by cURL session's result(curl_exec). please some help

What i have tried:

## 1 - preg_split

```
/* cURL initializations....*/
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$load_time = preg_split('//[@class="embedmain"]/.embedFooter/b', $result);
echo $load_time;
```

Output: `False` with an warning `preg_split(): Unknown modifier '['`

## 2 - HTML Parsing using DOMDocument

```
   /* cURL initializations....*/
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   $doc = new DOMDocument;
   $doc->loadHTML($result);
   $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
   $node = $xpath->query('//[@class="embedmain"]/.embedFooter/b')->item(0);       
   $load_time = (isset($node->textContent) && strlen($node->textContent) > 1 ? $node->textContent : '0.0ms');
   echo $load_time;
```

Output:

```
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression
Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on boolean
```

It looks like the xpath's query is invalid.

Comment: You need delimiters on the regex. You also have special characters in there, maybe you just want to use explode? Please provide sample HTML and what you are trying to parse.

Comment: the original HTML: https://pastebin.com/Wrv49c5L that <b>1406.081199646 ms</b> which iam trying to parse

Comment: Edit: i have tried to do something smilliar with regex but i failed again due to query problems  $regexp = '%(<b>[^\"]*?\</b>)%'; $load_time = preg_split($regexp, $result, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a regex for something like this, nor string functions. Use the parser and xpath as you started to do.

```
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$bold = $xpath->query('//div[@class="embedmain"]/div[@class="embedFooter"]/b')[0]->nodeValue;
echo $bold;
```

https://3v4l.org/A91Em